# Flutter isNegative called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this `isNegative` error when I want to show API reply, I don't know what made this error, can some one tell me what usually made this error?

Here's the full error:

`The getter 'isNegative' was called on null. Receiver: null`

Here's where the exception is caught:

```
Text(
  '${NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: 'id_ID')
      .format(
      double.tryParse(snapshot.data.dt_RpTag))}',
  style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16),
)
```

Comment: It will be great if you can post your entire part , it seems to me that you don't have the `snapshot.data` yet when you are using the `tryParse` method. However it will be clear once you post the other code

Comment: @gtxtreme Ah sorry, I just figure it out that the Api response that the data is null